# Catch "dead" session in Spring webflow

Tags: java, spring, session, exception, spring-webflow

I want to catch the exception thrown when I loose my session, not only because a session timeout (for reports for example).
Also I want that this handler will handle only that specific exception and will not be a global exceptions handler or any thing like this.
Basically, I want to catch exception `org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException`.

Answer (score 1):

With any of the proposed solutions below you should be able to handle the exceptions and perform logic on them.

**Possible Solutions:**

**1.** You can add a FlowExecutionListenerAdapter that will listen to all exceptions thrown and then you can filter by instanceof.

```
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.binding.mapping.MappingResult;
import org.springframework.webflow.engine.FlowAttributeMappingException;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext;

public class LoggingExceptionFlowExecutionListenerAdapter extends FlowExecutionListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void exceptionThrown(RequestContext context, FlowExecutionException exception) {
         if (exception instanceof HttpSessionRequiredException) {
                // do something
         } else if(exception instanceof FlowAttributeMappingException) {
                // do something else 
         }
    }
}
```

and you need to add it in your webflow executor config:

```
<bean id="loggingExceptionFlowExecutionListenerAdapter" class="my.package.LoggingExceptionFlowExecutionListenerAdapter"/>

<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry">
    <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
       <webflow:listener ref="loggingExceptionFlowExecutionListenerAdapter"        
    </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
</webflow:flow-executor>
```

**2.** Another solution is to implement your own FlowExecutionExceptionHandler. Although it will be a global exception handler The method

```
public void handle(FlowExecutionException exception,
            RequestControlContext context) { }
```

will allow you to have access to the context which will allow you to filter on many different variables. See also, [How implement the interface FlowExecutionExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506859/how-implement-the-interface-flowexecutionexceptionhandler)

**3.** Another possible solution if you are using Spring Security project I believe Spring security will handle the exception for you automatically if you have the follow config:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- rest of config omitted -->
        <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login"/>
</security:http>
```

and if you want to catch the exception and perform logic on it see the following answer: [Logout/Session timeout catching with spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843010/logout-session-timeout-catching-with-spring-security)

I would recommend the 3rd solution as it is the least intrusive. In the 3rd solution's link there are several really elegent solutions to handling sessions.