# Printing log from flow.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-webflow

I am working on a web application with spring web flow. While I am working on a `flow.xml` file I have get a decision state on it like this -

```
<decision-state id="checkPermissin">    
    <if test="requestParameters.canApprove" then="approve" else="warning" />
</decision-state>
```

When a request comes to the `flow.xml` then it get the request parameter `canApprove` from it and test whether it is true or false. Then it goes to the either of `approve` or `warning` state.

My question is - can I log/print the status of `canApprove` from the `flow.xml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an on-exit tag to the end of the 'decision-state' and call any service methods, spring beans, or static methods on the classpath.

Try this (untested):

```
<decision-state id="checkPermissin">    
    <if test="requestParameters.canApprove" then="approve" else="warning" />
   <on-exit>
        <evaluate expression="T(org.apache.log4j.Logger).getLogger('someLogger').info(requestParameters.canApprove)"/>
   </on-exit>
</decision-state>
```

The above solution is more of a hack to fulfill what you are asking for. The "proper" way to log this is to extend a FlowExecutionListenerAdapter and to listen for your current flow + decision-state id "checkPermissin" then log whatever you desire about that flow but it would involve more setup/coding outside the flow.xml file. (see: [Catch "dead" session in Spring webflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901635/catch-dead-session-in-spring-webflow/29924424#29924424)(Note): the example is for catching exceptions but can easily be adapted for logging anything in a flow)